# Mouse button stops working intermittently

Tags: debian, kernel, kali-linux, mouse

I have noticed that I'm not the only one with mouse button problems. This problem seems to affect multiple users on many different Linux versions regardless of Desktop versions (at least in Unity & Gnome.)

First time I noticed this was after the kernel upgrade so I think this has little to do with "Mouse" it self. It's not a problem with Bluetooth nor USB since the mouse moves while the problem occurs. Only the buttons stop working for a while. Best way to get the buttons back is to use the keyboard alt+tab switch combination or to switch tty with ALT+F3 and back.

It is truly annoying problem since it intermittently affect copy/paste of text (on browser) or drag & dropping - making life difficult. Reboot helps so far but is annoying.

Any help is appreciated.

Debian/Kali2/Gnome

Comment: Tested with Logitech & Microsoft mouse's.